# how to refer an external link from wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have created button and a text field in my wordpress page and when user add something and clicked search it will go to an external link to search.i tried this and my html and javescript as follows the thing is if i need to add a link like this `https://the outside site/index.php?NAME_PATH=DOMAINS_PATH` it will redirected in wordpress as this `http://server/mywordpressfolder/?domainname=dyhrrty&name=.com` so gives an 404 error how to resolve this!

```
 
    function callGetDomain() 
    { 
        var res1=$("#domainname").val();
        var res2=$("#name").val();
        var name=res1+res2; if(res1!="Domain Name")  {           
        location.href="https://www.google.lk/search?q=test"; }
        else { alert("Please Specify Domain Name"); }
    } 
 
<div class="search_domaim">
<div class="title_text">
 <h2>Register This Domain</h2></div>
<div class="search_field">
<form action="" method="get">
<div class="search_input">
<input name="domainname" type="text" class="textbox" id="domainname" onfocus="if (value == 'Domain Name') {value =''}" onblur="if (value == '') {value = 'Domain Name'}" value="Domain Name"></div>
<div class="search_drop">
<select name="name" id="name">
 <option value=".com">.com</option>
 <option value=".in">.in</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="search_btn">
<!--<input name="" type="image" src="images/domain_search_btn.png" />-->
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="domain_submit" onclick="callGetDomain();">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

it will run in normal way but in wordpress how to achieve this????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done using onCick method

Heres my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/gecfxfy6/)

```
$(".domain_submit").on("click",function(){

     var res1=$("#domainname").val();
    var res2=$("#name").val(); 
    var name=res1+res2; alert(name);
    if(res1!="Domain Name") { window.open('https://www.google.lk/search?q=test','_blank'); }
    else { alert("Please Specify Domain Name");
         }

});
```

Comment: thanks i am little new to this where should i put this does this should go to footr or header php in wordpress???

Comment: you can put the following code in header or footer anywhere ..preferably footer

Comment: thanks! it doesn't work either...! is this happens because of the theme i use???? if so is there any edits to do??

Comment: is the div structure mentioned in the question is part of theme or custom added one?

Comment: its a custom added one! do i need to remove it they are just for CSS!

Comment: hey i just got it correct!. what i did is adding my URL path to the form action attribute now its OK! but one thing unclear! Do we always need to set that, if we use custom functions? isn't it enough mentioning method as get or post ?

Comment: if we add custom functions we need to do some tweaks .. Cheers it helped you